# nodejs module not wowrking inside a function

Tags: node.js, port, child-process

i am having an issue with nodejs

the function bellow works fine

```
const process = require('detect-port');
port = 9090;
detect(port, (err, _port) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }else if (port == _port) {
   console.log("started");
   backgroundProcess();
  } else {
   console.log(`port: ${port} was occupied, try port: ${_port}`);
  }
});
```

but does not work inside a function 
i would like to know why and how to make it work

```
function lunchnd(){
const process = require('detect-port');
port = 9090;
detect(port, (err, _port) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }else if (port == _port) {
   console.log("started");
   backgroundProcess();
  } else {
   console.log(`port: ${port} was occupied, try port: ${_port}`);
  }
});
}

lunchnd();
```

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: Explain the why. If you already tried copying other code it probably is not homework, right? If it's for a real-world task, don't implement it yourself.

Comment: You can use `scipy.optimize.linprog` for this. I think that is easier that the aforementioned repository. The first one would be `scipy.optimize.linprog([-2, -1], [[1, 1], [1, -1]], [10, 20])`. The second one you can probably do by yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

In a few minutes, I found some implementations in Python including this one:
https://github.com/igobrilhante/simplex/blob/master/simplex.py

As any algorithm, there are no "secrets", you just have to implement each part of it. The easiest would probably be to start from a "pseudocode" perspective and write methods in the right spots. If your methods are placed in a sound order, then you can focus on implementing them one by one.

Of course, take a simple example that you've solved on paper to double check your work.